# How do you place text above a parent in unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

In my unity platformer game I have got an enemy with a simple patrolling script I would like to have text placed above him and it stays there. How could I go about doing this?

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(hit.collider != false)
    {
        if (isFacingRight)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
            
        }
        else
        {

            
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-transform.localScale.x, 1f, 1f);
        m_Object.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-transform.localScale.x, 1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `TextMeshPro` package, and add a TextMesh as a child of the enemy, just above its head. This will keep the text over it

Comment: Great, However in my patrolling script it goes right then left how can I make it so the text doesn't flip as well.

Comment: detect if the character is flipped and then set the local scale x of the text to 1 or -1

Comment: also, you could just flip the sprite and not the whole gameobject. up to youz

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new how do I set the local scale x to 1 or -1, I will edit the question to include the patrol script.